# Oracle Linux hangs on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, oracle, windows-8.1

I am trying to install Oracle Linux 7.0 on Hyper-V. While I click through the GUI installer the system stops responding. The mouse cursor stays in the same place.

It happened to me a few times, everytime in a different menu. 
It's not the case of capturing the mouse or something like that. I have successfully installed other VMs including CentOS 7 and many Windows machines.

I don't even know how to troubleshoot this. The only common thing that I have observed is the virtual CPU utilization (22-23%) and 988MB of RAM consumed during all the crashes.

Comment: I downloaded an OEL version 7.7, and had the same problem on Hyper-V. I'd exported the VMDK to VHD, but the machine just hung at boot, keyboard unresponsive. Oddly, the keyboard worked fine when selecting the boot O/S (from the list of 1, lol). I realize this is a really old question, but yea, the problem is still there.